# Magento 2 - How to translate JS form errors?

Tags: magento2, javascript, translate

In Magento 2, I try to translate Javascript messages `"This is a required field."`

In create account form :

[image]

I selected Spanish language but javascript errors are not translated, they appears in English.

Can you tell me what steps to take to correct this problem ?

**EDIT**

The message is in the following file: `lib/web/mage/validation.js`

```
$.validator.messages = $.extend($.validator.messages, {
    required: $.mage.__('This is a required field.'),
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > app/design/frontend/Theme/name/i18n/code_ISO.csv

   ```
   "This is a required field.","Translation here", Magento_Ui
   ```

   > for Spanish language code_ISO.csv = es_ES.csv
2. Flush cache. `php bin/magento c:f`
3. Deploy static content: `php bin/magento s:s:d es_ES -f`

Comment: what do they stand for code_ISO code_ISO.csv, just to understand only

Comment: You can check this : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Comment: I tried but nothing changes, the text is not translated.

Comment: Do you have this in js file 'mage/translate' 
$.mage.__('This is a required field.')); - example
Not sure would this work

Comment: @jibingeorge Yes, you can see my update in my question

Comment: is this a custom module? if it is can't you create i18n file in your custom module instead of frontend/Theme/

Comment: It's not custom module, it's in lib/web/mage/validation.js file. I also add translation in lib/web/i18n/es_ES.csv but doesn't work

Comment: @Fabien please look my update `Magento_Ui` and not `Magento_Customer` then ...

Comment: @PЯINCƏ Thanks but it still does not work...

Comment: I also tried in app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/i18n/es_ES.csv and  app/i18n/mageplaza/es_ES/es_ES.csv but nothing work